# Python: Handover a variable while calling a module

Tags: python, function, variables, import, module

In python, I would like to call a self-built module and hand it over a certain variable (e.g. an integer number).
By this, I would like to specify from which file a module is called, i.e. when I import the module XY from file A, the module shall work in a certain mode (specified by the variable) and if I import module XY from a file B, the module shall work in another mode

My first idea was to do this by defining functions; but when I have plenty of functions in my module, I would have to add this extra variable in every single function individually.

Is there a **more elegant way to assign a module a certain variable/ operation mode when importing** it?

```
import mymodule # here, I'd like to hand-over a global variable to "mymodule" which can be used in the source-code of "mymodule"

mymodule.any_function_from_it()
```

The module "mymodule" may have the following structure:

```
def any_function_from_it_independent_from_global_variable():
   print("x")
   # more code to follow here

if variable_handed_over==0:
   def any_function_from_it():
      print("xy")
      # more code to follow here

else:
   def any_function_from_it():
      print("xyz")
      # more code to follow here
```

Comment: Hi. Give this a try https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__init__-in-python/

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of how a function from `mymodule` might use a global variable if it had one.

Comment: From your example you just need different modules: `mymodule1` and `mymodule2` etc. Then you just need to import the right module from `A` or `B`.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of different ways to achieve the general end result you seem to want - but "configuring a module to behave differently based on the value of a 'passed variable' when importing" isn't one of them.

Here is a module that shows two common approaches to doing something like what you describe. The first approach, using the class `ThingDoer` is an object-oriented approach. The second approach, using the function `get_thing_doer` is a functional approach.

Module: `doers.py`

```py
class ThingDoer(object):
    def __init__(self, is_special_mode=False):
        self._is_special_mode = is_special_mode


    def _special_mode_do_it(self):
        print("I'm special!")

    def _do_it(self):
        print("I'm not special, but please accept me anyway")

    def do_the_thing(self):
        if self._is_special_mode:
            self._special_mode_do_it()
            return

        self._do_it()



def get_thing_doer(is_special_mode=False):
    def special_mode_do_it():
        print("I'm special")

    def do_it():
        print("I'm not special, but please accept me anyway")

    if is_special_mode:
        return special_mode_do_it

    return do_it
```

You can play with how this works by creating another module in the same directory.

Module: `do_it.py`

```py
from doers import get_thing_doer, ThingDoer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = ThingDoer()  # is_special_mode argument takes default value of False
    foo.do_the_thing()  # prints: "I'm not special, but please love me anyway!"

    bar = ThingDoer(is_special_mode=True)
    bar.do_the_thing()  # prints: "I'm Special!"

    bazz = get_thing_doer()  # is_special_mode argument takes default value of False
    bazz()  # prints: "I'm not special, but please love me anyway!"

    buzz = get_thing_doer(is_special_mode=True)
    buzz()  # prints "I'm special!"
```

Then, from the command line run: `python do_it.py`.

More abstractly: in python conditional behaviors are not typically managed based on stateful configuration at *import* time.

Instead, conditional behaviors (based on configuration, or some other application state) happens as part of the flow of your program's execution.